# Составить программу для нахождения общего количества заданной буквы в трех заданных предложениях

Tags: c++

Программа считает количество заданной буквы, только в первом предложении. Как сделать так, чтобы программа считала не только в первом, но и во втором и в третьем.
[image: Пример работы кода]

```
int Func(string a, string c, string v, char b)
{
    return count(a.begin(), a.end(), b);
    return count(c.begin(), c.end(), b);
    return count(v.begin(), v.end(), b);
}

int main()
{
setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian");

string a, c, v;
char b;

cout << "Введите первое предложение: " << endl;
getline(cin, a);

cout << "Введите второе предложение: " << endl;
getline(cin, c);
cout << "Введите третье предложение: " << endl;
getline(cin, v);

cout << "Введите букву: " << endl;
cin >> b;
cout << Func(a,c,v, b) << endl;
```

Comment: вызывать функцию три раза? или возвращать массив int[] с ответами?

Comment: Взять учебник и прочитать что делает return.

Comment: Если вам надо общее количество - суммируйте три `count`, если по отдельности - передавайте в функцию одно предложение, и вызывайте ее три раза. Впрочем, с точки зрения логичности :) лучше в любом случае иметь функцию для одного предложения, и суммировать результаты ее вызовов...

Comment: Приведите [mre], который можно модифицировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Func(string a, char b)
{
    return count(a.begin(), a.end(), b);
}

int main()
{
setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian");

string a, c, v;
char b;

cout << "Введите первое предложение: " << endl;
getline(cin, a);

cout << "Введите второе предложение: " << endl;
getline(cin, c);
cout << "Введите третье предложение: " << endl;
getline(cin, v);

cout << "Введите букву: " << endl;
cin >> b;
cout << Func(a, b) << endl;
cout << Func(c, b) << endl;
cout << Func(v, b) << endl;
```